# RDLC report does not work when published and hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, rdlc

I have my project solution in a server and the project exports RDLC reports based on export path. When I run the solution, the exports work charmingly and get downloaded at the right path. However, when I publish the solution and host it in IIS, I see the following error:

[image]

On the response tab of developer tool I see the below error:

{"d":"{"Is_Error":true,"Error_Desc":"\u003cb\u003eOops! Exporting Error Occured: \u003c/b\u003eValue cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: bytes"}"}

The controller is however having 200 response code, I still see this error. any help on how this can be solved?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, finally I found the answer for this. Published RDLC files does not have any markup in them. so the exports does not work since the controller cannot read the RDLC file content. so I copied the raw RDLC to the published project folder and it worked just fine!